# Error in my sql (varchar2)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, varchar2

I have the following error in all my tables where I am using varchar2

> error ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column

although I have used characters less than the specified length

[image]

**Note:** I am using oracle apex

Comment: Help us help you - please share your table definition and the failing SQL statement.

Comment: and when i choose varchar2 i can't insert a precision

Comment: I have inserted an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the screenshot, it is the DEP_ID that raises the error, not DEP_NAME. It seems that you wrongly defined that column in the table. This is what you did:

```
SQL> create table test (dep_id number(1, 10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (dep_id) values (1);
insert into test (dep_id) values (1)
                                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column


SQL> insert into test (dep_id) values (0.0000000001);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

In other words, you set precision to "1" (i.e. allow only one significant digit), while scale is set to "10" (which represents "decimal" digits).

For your sake, in this case set `DEP_ID NUMBER`, without precision or scale.